# Recursively find connectivity in a 2D Array

Tags: java, swing, recursion, jframe

I have a game and I'm having trouble implementing the scores.
Prof stated that it must be recursively done without a for-loop. But I'm having trouble thinking of the algorithm that is used. This is the game.

The score system works so it starts with the valve pipe (Pipe.ValvePipe) and then it checks to see how many pipes are connected to it. Is there a certain algorithm/strategy for doing this type of recursion? Thank you in advance.

pipe.java
public class Pipe {
    private boolean openAtTop;
    private boolean openAtRight;
    private boolean openAtBottom;
    private boolean openAtLeft;
    private boolean isValve;

```
private static Pipe     VALVE_PIPE;

public Pipe(boolean t, boolean r, boolean b, boolean l, boolean valve) {
    openAtTop = t; openAtBottom = b; openAtRight = r; openAtLeft = l;
    isValve = valve;
}

public boolean isValve() { return isValve; }
public static Pipe ValvePipe() { return new Pipe(false, false, true, false, true); }

public boolean isValid() { return !(!openAtTop&&!openAtBottom&&!openAtLeft&&!openAtRight); }
public static Pipe RandomPipe() {
    Pipe p;
    do {
        p = new Pipe(Math.random() < 0.5, Math.random() < 0.5,
                    Math.random() < 0.5, Math.random() < 0.5, false);
    } while (!p.isValid());
    return p;
}

public boolean isOpenAtTop() { return openAtTop; }
public boolean isOpenAtBottom() { return openAtBottom; }
public boolean isOpenAtLeft() { return openAtLeft; }
public boolean isOpenAtRight() { return openAtRight; }

public boolean fitsBelow(Pipe p) {
    return (p == null) || (!openAtTop && !p.isOpenAtBottom()) || (openAtTop && p.isOpenAtBottom());
}
public boolean fitsAbove(Pipe p) {
    return (p == null) || (!openAtBottom && !p.isOpenAtTop()) || (openAtBottom && p.isOpenAtTop());
}
public boolean fitsToLeftOf(Pipe p) {
    return (p == null) || (!openAtRight && !p.isOpenAtLeft()) || (openAtRight && p.isOpenAtLeft());
}
public boolean fitsToRightOf(Pipe p) {
    return (p == null) || (!openAtLeft && !p.isOpenAtRight()) || (openAtLeft && p.isOpenAtRight());
}

public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    if (openAtTop) s+="1"; else s+="0";
    if (openAtRight) s+="1"; else s+="0";
    if (openAtBottom) s+="1"; else s+="0";
    if (openAtLeft) s+="1"; else s+="0";
    return s;
}
public int toInt() {
    int s = 0;
    if (openAtTop) s+=8;
    if (openAtRight) s+=4;
    if (openAtBottom) s+=2;
    if (openAtLeft) s+=1;
    return s;
}
```

}

```
PipeGameView.java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// Subclass JFrame so you can display a window
public class PipeGameView extends JPanel {
    private PipeGame        game;       // The model

    private BoardPanel      tiles;
    private JButton[][]     buttons;
    private JProgressBar    timeBar;
    private JButton         startStop;
    private JRadioButton    twoMinButton, tenMinButton, noLimitButton;
    private JLabel          statusLabel;

    // This constructor builds the window
    public PipeGameView(PipeGame g) {
        game = g;       // Store the model for access in update()

        // Set up the components
        tiles = new BoardPanel();
        tiles.setLayout(new GridLayout(game.getRows(), game.getRows()));
        buttons = new JButton[game.getRows()][game.getRows()];

        // Add the buttons to the tile panel
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("Pipes0000.GIF");
        for (int r=0; r<game.getRows(); r++) {
            for (int c=0; c<game.getRows(); c++) {
                buttons[r][c] = new JButton(ic);
                tiles.add(buttons[r][c]);
            }
        }

        // Now layout the components using a gridbag layout
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints layoutConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.setLayout(layout);

        // Add the Start/Stop Button
        startStop = new JButton("Start Game");
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 0; layoutConstraints.gridy = 0;
        layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 1; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        layoutConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        layoutConstraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        layoutConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        layoutConstraints.weightx = 0.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
        layout.setConstraints(startStop, layoutConstraints);
        this.add(startStop);

        // Add the JRadioButtons
        twoMinButton = new JRadioButton("2 minutes");
        tenMinButton = new JRadioButton("10 minutes");
        noLimitButton = new JRadioButton("No Time Limit");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(twoMinButton); group.add(tenMinButton); group.add(noLimitButton);

        layoutConstraints.gridx = 1;
        layout.setConstraints(twoMinButton, layoutConstraints);
        this.add(twoMinButton);
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 2;
        layout.setConstraints(tenMinButton, layoutConstraints);
        this.add(tenMinButton);
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 3;
        layout.setConstraints(noLimitButton, layoutConstraints);
        this.add(noLimitButton);

        // Add the tiles
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 0; layoutConstraints.gridy = 1;
        layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 4; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        layoutConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        layoutConstraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        layoutConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        layoutConstraints.weightx = 0.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
        layout.setConstraints(tiles, layoutConstraints);
        this.add(tiles);

        // Add the label
        statusLabel = new JLabel("Time Left: ");
        statusLabel.setVisible(false);
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 0; layoutConstraints.gridy = 2;
        layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 1; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        layoutConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        layoutConstraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        layoutConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        layoutConstraints.weightx = 0.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
        layout.setConstraints(statusLabel, layoutConstraints);
        this.add(statusLabel);

        timeBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        timeBar.setValue(100);
        timeBar.setVisible(false);
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 1; layoutConstraints.gridy = 2;
        layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 3; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        layoutConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        layoutConstraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        layoutConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        layoutConstraints.weightx = 5.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
        layout.setConstraints(timeBar, layoutConstraints);
        this.add(timeBar);
        update();
    }

    // Get methods for the components
    public JButton getButton(int r, int c) { return buttons[r][c]; }
    public JButton getStartStopButton() { return startStop; }
    public JProgressBar getTimeBar() { return timeBar; }
    public JRadioButton getTwoMinButton() { return twoMinButton; }
    public JRadioButton getTenMinButton() { return tenMinButton; }
    public JRadioButton getNoLimitButton() { return noLimitButton; }

    public void setGame(PipeGame g) { game = g; }


    // This is called whenever the model has changed.  Note that this code is not efficient.   All ICONS should really
    // be loaded upon game start and stored into a static array of ImageIcons.   Then, these static icons should be
    // used instead of re-creating icons each time.
    public void update() {
        // Update the look of the buttons
        for (int r=0; r<game.getRows(); r++) {
            for (int c=0; c<game.getRows(); c++) {
                if (game.isOver())
                    buttons[r][c].setEnabled(false);
                else
                    buttons[r][c].setEnabled(true);

                if (game.getPipe(r,c) == null)
                    buttons[r][c].setSelected(false);
                else {
                    // Determine the portion of the icon's filename that matches the pipe
                    String currentPipeCodes = "Start";
                    if (!game.getPipe(r,c).isValve())
                        currentPipeCodes = game.getPipe(r,c).toString();
                    buttons[r][c].setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("pipes"+ currentPipeCodes +".GIF"));
                    buttons[r][c].setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        }

        // Update the start/stop button
        if (game.isOver())
            startStop.setText("Start");
        else
            startStop.setText("Stop");

        // Update the radio buttons
        if (game.isOver()) {
            twoMinButton.setEnabled(true);
            tenMinButton.setEnabled(true);
            noLimitButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else {
            twoMinButton.setEnabled(false);
            tenMinButton.setEnabled(false);
            noLimitButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        // Update the status label
        if (game.isOver()) {
            statusLabel.setText("Final Score: " + game.getPlacedPipes());
            statusLabel.setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            if (game.getStyle() == 2) {
                statusLabel.setVisible(false);
            }
            else {
                statusLabel.setText("Time Left: ");
                statusLabel.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        // Update the timer bar
        if (game.isOver() || (game.getStyle() == 2)) {
            timeBar.setVisible(false);
        }
        else {
            timeBar.setValue((int)(game.getTimeRemaining() / (float)game.getTimeLimit() * 100));
            timeBar.setVisible(true);
        }

        // Update the cursor
        ImageIcon i;
        if (game.isOver()) {
            tiles.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }
        else {
            if (game.getNextPipe().isValve())
                i = new ImageIcon("pipesStart.GIF");
            else
                i = new ImageIcon("pipes"+ game.getNextPipe().toString() +".GIF");
            tiles.setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(i.getImage(), new Point(0,0), "pipe"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is you recursion code? It will be hard if you put all unnecessary information.

Comment: I don't have a recursion code yet because I'm having trouble writing one. I'm asking what type of algorithm/strategy would I use to count all the pipes connected to the valve pipe.

Comment: can you truncate all that to just the relevant stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt go through all your code but as a hint the function would look like this:

```
getScore( Pipe p ){
  if ( p == null ) return 0;
  int res = 1; // size of this pipe
  res += getScore(leftPipe);
  res += getScore(rightPipe);
  ...
  return res;
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to includes the row and col to calculate the pipes that are connected to the main starting pipe

```
public void connectedPipes(int row, int col){
    if(row == null) return 0;
    int res = 1; // size of this pipe
    res += getScore(leftPipe);
    res += getScore(rightPipe);
    return res;
}
```